# Are there methods for iron content determination in spinach that do not require thiocyanate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I am looking for a way to measure the iron content of spinach for a chemistry experiment. Unfortunately I am not sure that thiocyanate will be available and I'm therefore trying to find an alternate method. The most common one seem to be a titration with potassium permanganate. The issue with this method is that other much more abundant metals in spinach would also react with the permanganate.

I had the idea to ash the spinach, dissolve the ashes in water. Then use a displacement reaction since iron is the least reactive metal in the chemical makeup of spinach. I am not sure exactly how but I thought it might be possible to use a compound to precipitate the more reactive ions out of solutions.

Do any of you have some ideas regarding this experiment?

Comment: I suppose you need to dissolve ash in acid, otherwise iron could end as insoluble oxides ( or metal if highly heated with carbonized organics ). The iron oxidation state after dissolution can be uncertain, as oxides tend to be non-stoichiometric and reducting environment during burning undefined.

Comment: Through spectrometer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18435/how-to-determine-the-iron-content-in-spinach-with-a-spectrometer?r=SearchResults

Comment: Or through titration: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42866/how-to-determine-the-iron-content-in-spinach-from-a-titration-with-permanganate?r=SearchResults

Comment: @NilayGhosh yes I am looking for a method other than the spectrometer since I may not have access to KSCN. The problem with that titration is that many other metals will react with the permanganate.

Comment: @Poutnik How could I proceed from them to determine the amount of iron in the solution?

Comment: Hm, with avoiding instrumental techniques ,including spectrometers, it would be difficult, as manganometry may not be specific enough. But anyway, only about 2% of spinach iron ( 2-2.7 mg/100g) would be available for a body, as it is mostly blocked by oxalate, compared to 15-35% by meat sources, where iron is mostly bond in the [heme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heme).

Comment: @Poutnik I thought oxalate could be "broken down" by cooking/ashing? Yeah manganometry seems like it would be imprecise since so many other metals would react with the manganate. Thats why I was thinking of using another compound before the manganate to precipitate all the iron out of the ash solution, given iron is one of the least reactive metals in spinach. Do you think there would be a way to do this?

Comment: I have read oxalate content drops by spinach cooking from 1000mg/100g to one half.

Comment: Spinach is not specially rich in iron. $100$ g spinach contains $3.1$ mg Fe. $100$ g beans contains $6.1$ mg Fe. Lentils  $8.6$ mg/$100$ g.. Soja$ 8.4$ mg/$100$ g. Nutmegs $4.5$ mg/$100$ g.   Ref.: K. Diem. C. Lentner, Tables scientifiques, CIBA-Geigy SA, Basel, Switzerland, $1972$, p. $511 - 515$.

Comment: $100$ g fresh spinach contains $662$ mg $\ce{K}$, $106$ mg $\ce{Ca}$,  $65$ mg $\ce{Cl}$, $62$ mg $\ce{Na}$ , $62$ mg $\ce{Mg}$, $51$ mg $\ce{P}$, $27$ mg $\ce{S}$, $3.1$ mg $\ce{Fe}$, $0.82$ mg $\ce{Mn}$, $0.2$ mg $\ce{Cu}$. From the same reference as in my previous message.

Comment: Don't go reinventing the wheel, there are literature values for the iron contents of vegetables, and that literature comes with procedures how they were determined.

Comment: @Karl I understand, but my means are more limited

Comment: @ Hugo. Iron(III) can be titrated by EDTA $0.02$ M at pH$ 2.5$ and $45$°C. The indicator is thiosalicylic acid, which goes from red to colorless. If you can obtain this indicator, I will give you the detailed process. 1 mL EDTA $0.02$ M corresponds to $1.2$ mg Fe. This fits your needs. Ca and Mg do not disturb. Titration of Fe(II) can be done by KMnO4, but the iron must first be reduced by a Walden column (metallic silver). I also may give you the process, if you have got such a column.

Comment: @Maurice, What reference book do you have? It seems to have a lot of classical analyses.

Comment: @ Farooq. You are right. My reference book contains more than one hundred inorganic titrations with EDTA. It is a wonderful booklet called "Méthodes d'analyses complexométriques avec l'EDTA", 116 p., edited by Merck, Darmstadt, 1973. Unfortunately it is written in French.

Comment: @Maurice Any change you could send me a picture of that specific titration? My first language is French so that won't be a problem.

Comment: @ Hugo. I don't know how to add a picture to my message. So I copy the titration here. The sample can contain up to $35$ mg Fe. Dilute it up to $100$ mL. Adjust the pH to about $2.5$ with $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{HCl}$ $ 0.1$ M. Check with indicator paper pH $0-6$. Add $1$ mL indicator ($5$ g sulfo-$5$-salicylic acid in $95$ g water). Heat to $45$°C and titrate the red solution with $\ce{Na2EDTA}$ $0.02$ M up to discoloration. This method gives only Fe(III). If the total iron content $\ce{Fe(II) + Fe(III)}$ is to be determined, the sample must be heated to boiling with $1$ mL conc. nitric acid.

Comment: @Maurice Merci beaucoup

Comment: I've used the ferrozine method before.  This review gives three different methods, one of which is the ferrozine method, and at a first glance, none of them require thiocyanate.  https://aslopubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.4319/lom.2013.11.113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are iron testing kits in water which are available at an affordable price. I have not used them but read more about them here [Testing iron in well water](https://yourh2home.com/best-iron-test-kit-well-water-reviews/). You can test your spinach extracts for a yes no type answer if iron is present in significant quantities or not. Just keep in mind that PopEye's spinach is really not that rich in iron. Too much iron is a liver toxin.

I am afraid to share the bad news for you that with the resources you have, you cannot reliably determine iron content in spinach. Micronutrients or minerals cannot be determined by classical methods because they are present in a complex matrix and in very small quantities (parts per million range). They need instrumental analysis (absorption by molecular complexes, atomic emission or atomic absorption). I saw a couple of papers from ResearchGate which talk about the titration of spinach extract with permanganate. Nothing can be more wrong than this procedure in analytical chemistry. They are basically titrating all the organic stuff with it. Those methods are horribly wrong. Someone on SE Chemistry posted a query on how to determine iron in spinach by titration [Iron in spinach](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42866/how-to-determine-the-iron-content-in-spinach-from-a-titration-with-permanganate)...that is all incorrect. Yes, you will generate some numbers with those burette readings but those numbers have no significance.

Regarding your ashing method, that will not work either, because you need at several kgs of spinach to get a small amount (milligram) of iron. What should be the ashing temperature? How would you isolate iron from the ashes? Selective precipitation to get rid of other minerals? Nope, that is a bigger headache. For that you would need more reagents.

If this is a school project, make sure you have the resources after searching the literature. If this is an home experiment- classical methods will not work.

Answer (score -2):

As you are looking for inventive ways to possibly measure Fe presence for a school presentation, may I suggest a crude (but likely interesting) visual aid in possibly determining relative iron concentration.

One idea is that Fe ions in the presence of acidic H2O2 will engage in radical production. The latter reaction in the presence of suitable light over time could result in a cyclic reaction system (for example, [photo-Fenton](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128104996000036)). The latter is a conceivable path to magnify even small transition metals presence.

The latter radicals (especially, the powerful hydroxyl radical) can breakdown organic matter, including, for example, a strongly colored dye over time, resulting in eventual de-colorization. The relative periodic time evolution for the latter could be a manner to simply display/document apparent differences in even small relative iron (also copper, manganese,..) concentrations.

Here is a citation from the literature as an example, [Effect of iron salt on the color removal of water containing the azo-dye reactive blue 69 using photo-assisted Fe(II)/H2O2 and Fe(III)/H2O2 systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1010603008001184).

So, spinach grown in iron-rich soil, reduced to ash added to acidic H2O2 (plus perhaps more acid added 1st to the spinach,  further lowering pH) in the presence of a photo-sensitive dye subject to photolysis, should display more rapid de-colorization (as captured by periodic snapshots) than one grown in iron-poor soil.

You may experiment with various ways of numerically quantifying the tentative iron content, as deemed viable given limited resources (including funds which alternatively, could purchase an iron testing kit, available [here](https://www.letsgetchecked.com/us/en/home-iron-test/?imp=cpc&lgc_code=SELFCARE&lgc_saving=30&gclid=CjwKCAjwkJj6BRA-EiwA0ZVPVrDhNRZc_pTEJYv_6gFvLIXNf2b26Nu9aYw6bsjwZVxIycQjPiawyBoCKm4QAvD_BwE), for example, at $99, or less expensive water testing strips [here](https://www.cleanwaterstore.com/iron-test-kits.html?matchtype=b&network=g&device=c&keyword=&campaign=8077533048&adgroup=83465604197&keyword=&_vsrefdom=wordstream&keyword_session_id=vt%7Eadwords%7Ckt%7E%7Cmt%7Eb%7Cta%7E396481862628&gclid=CjwKCAjwkJj6BRA-EiwA0ZVPVrmg15SrFZO1-uX2JnDVkyX2cIGvbYawuK5le26FEI42z5uu4yBuYhoC24AQAvD_BwE)).

Note: I am assuming one does not have the time to actually grow the same variety of spinach. Otherwise, I would simply speculate that iron-richer spinach may possess different coloration (and perhaps other discernable quantifiable attributes) for the purpose of a simple relative classification as to iron content.

This would conceptually be based, relatedly to above, on naturally occurring photosynthesis. To quote from a [supporting source](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0967026042000202127):

> Iron, one of the structural elements of organic components that play an essential role in photosynthesis and nitrogen assimilation of plants, is available at extremely low concentrations in large parts of the Southern Ocean's surface waters. We tested the hypothesis that photosynthesis is the primary target of iron stress in phytoplankton living in this specific environment, resulting in a reduced carbohydrate production.

On the suggested coloration argument relating to iron content, also a [confirming reference](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/vegetable-plants-contain-large-amounts-iron-30866.html), to quote:

> Leafy vegetables featuring a deep, dark green color, such as spinach and collard greens, are usually high in iron.